What is the difference between a voucher and a gift certificate?
Is my assumption about the difference correct?:A voucher features a specific service or product that you can get for free at a specific place whereas a gift certificate features a specific monetary value for which you can buy products or services at a given place/given places.
If my assumption is not correct, can you please tell me the actual differences?
I know that a voucher is usually given by a business as compensation and that a gift card is a gift that one person gives to another.

This question has already been asked three times on ELU.

You shouldn't cross-post, in case you have...

(1.) Is this the difference between a voucher and a gift card? (2.) What's the difference between a voucher and a gift card? (3.) Is my assumption about the difference between a voucher and a gift card correct? If not, can you please tell me the differences?


"a gift certificate features a specific monetary value"

Your assumption is incorrect. A gift certificate can be for a product. The important point is that the receiver gets to choose the gift. It's usually a cash value to allow a wide variety of gifts from that store.
A voucher is for a specific thing, like a replacement toaster under warranty or a hotel room when they cancel your flight.
A voucher is an emotionless business obligation. A gift certificate brings joy.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

A gift certificate is generally something that is purchased and then given to a recipient (as the name says as a gift). A voucher can be given for any number of reasons, business attendance, promotion, rebate.
An easy way to think of it, all gift certificates are vouchers, not all gift certificates are vouchers. (Although a particular retail establishment might well distribute all of these as something labelled "gift certificate" for ease of administration, simply because actual gift certificates are by far the most common form they deal in).

Ty but what about my assumption?

You wrote "all gift certificates are vouchers, not all gift certificates are vouchers." Did you mean "all gift certificates are vouchers, not all vouchers are gift certificates"?

A gift certificate is a gift of some amount of money (value) given to someone in the form of a printed paper or electronic message with the name of the retail business on it that allows the gift recipient to purchase something at a given store/shop or business. It is issued by a store/shop or business or service provider (hair dressers, for example) in an amount the purchaser of the gift certificate wishes to give someone.It's a present.
A voucher shows an amount of money (value) determined by a shop/store or retail business, usually for merchandise that has been returned to them, which the recipient (the original purchaser) can use in that same shop/store or business to pay for or toward another purchase in the same business. Some businesses which do not accept returns of merchandise in exchange for cash or credit (to a credit card), issue vouchers instead of credit or cash. Vouchers are not presents.
Both gift certificates and vouchers are used by many businesses or shops/stores.

Ty but what about my assumption?

@ldk29 I answered that by explaining the difference so your assumption is wrong. And vouchers are not compensation. Vouchers, like I said in my answer, are for specific amounts and are given in lieu of  reimbursement in cash or credit when you return products to stores and they allow you to get something else for the amount shown. Now, I've said it again.
